# At what % about the stock price should I sell and take my profits?

Tags: economics, volatility, politics

at what percentage above the cost price should you walk? prices fluctuate therefore? what should the end point be?

Comment: I have lost beefy profits in past trades because I wasn't sure when to get out.

Comment: This is too subjective, it depends on your goals, your belief in the company who's shares you hold, etc.

Comment: Does it mean once you are convinced in a company it's by for keeps until otherwise? come rain or shine? really? not practical

Comment: What is practical depends on the situation. My grandma has a bunch of AT&T shares from working/retiring from one of the companies that they ended up buying. They pay a dividend and are pretty stable, she's not interested in selling them, it's very practical for her to keep them indefinitely. If you narrow the scope of the question it could be answerable.

Answer (score 3):

General reasons for investors for when to sell a stock:

- The fundamentals have changed
- Share price has risen dramatically and you think that the stock has become overvalued
- You now believe that the purchase was a mistake
- Tax loss harvesting
- You need the money
- You found a better opportunity
- Your target price has been reached
- To cut losses
- Never

It's a somewhat different set of rules for a trader.